# Table of Contents Titles Spanning Two Lines

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]I have a table of contents with titles that span more than one line.  How can I get those page numbers to line up to the right?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, can you add a screenshot or further description?

Comment: @Adam, do you see how the second page number doesn't go all the way to the right?

Comment: What version of Word? In 2013, the auto toc correctly formats the number to the right. Can you try inserting an extra word in the title to make it slightly longer to check it isn't an edge case?

Comment: Hi @user994165 Could you please let me know how you solved it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your image, the page number is being forced to the next line (wrapping) because of the length and position of the title. The title appears to reach the margin on the right.

To resolve this, you can either shorten the title, reduce the indent or increase the margins on the page to accommodate the width required to get it on one line.